# SWIG equivalent of storing a boost::python::object

Tags: c++, python, swig, boost-python

What is the SWIG equivalent to storing a copy of an arbitrary python object?

I'm pretty sure what I'm asking is possible because it would work with boost::python (see below), but I can't see a way to do this using SWIG.

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

class MyClass
{
public:
    // other operations
    object get_info() { return info_; }
    void set_info(object info) { info_ = info; }

private:
    object info_;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE( mymodule )
{
    class_<MyClass>("MyClass")
        .def("get_info", &MyClass::get_info )
        .def("set_info", &MyClass::set_info )
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest example is:

```
%module test

%inline %{
class MyClass
{
public:
    // other operations
    PyObject *get_info() { return info_; }
    void set_info(PyObject *info) { info_ = info; }

private:
    PyObject *info_;
};
%}
```

e.g.:

```
swig -python -Wall -c++ test.i
g++ -Wall -Wextra test_wrap.cxx -I/usr/include/python2.6 -o _test.so -shared
python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 27 2010, 00:02:40)
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test
>>> foo = test.MyClass()
>>> str = "hi"
>>> foo.set_info(str)
>>> print foo.get_info()
hi
>>>
```

But note that in this case the ownership of the object has not been changed. If I'd done `foo.set_info("hi")` instead then it would have been released because no references were retained by the time it called `foo.get_info()`.

You can fix that by adding a call to:

```
Py_INCREF(info);
```

inside `set_info()`, but then you'll need a corresponding DECREF in the destructor, or if `set_info()` is called when a reference is already held, or for copy construction or assignment. (Or some nice RAII type to do all that for you...)

Comment: So provided the class is noncopyable a single naive INCREF/DEFREF is sufficient? I don't have to worry about any other special cases?

Comment: @AndrewWalker - depends how naive you're thinking. If you call set with one already having been set you need to DECREF. When you destroy you need to DECREF also. I'd really suggest going for the RAII approach - far harder to get it wrong.